# How to obtain an array from type TByteArray as part of a larger array from type TByteArray?

Tags: delphi, pointers, dynamic-arrays, lazarus, freepascal

I define a large typed dynamic array **aArray**. And now want to have a second array **bArray** marking a certain area in **aArray** without beeing a copy!

```
type
  TByteArray = array of Byte;

implementation

procedure SomeCode;
var 
  aArray : TByteArray;
  bArray : TByteArray;
begin
  setlength(aArray, 30);
  aArray[4] := 12;
  // here want to have bArray to hold 20 Bytes starting from Byte 5 in aArray 
  if bArray[0] = aArray[4] then begin
    writeln('All OK'); 
  end;

end;
```

Comment: If you edit your question and explain why you need to do this, you might get an answer that better fits your *actual* needs.

Comment: It's also a little bit disconcerting not knowing what compiler and language you are using. Is it Delphi? Is it FPC? Are you writing code to compile under both? Or are you just including the Delphi tag to hopefully attract more viewers of the question?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. I want to do this to get access to a data section into aArray with a diffrent meaning. This would give me elegant access to this sections of the raw data chunk. It helps me to write clear code wihout this position calculations Offset + counter etc. And it will save a copy operation.

Comment: I guessed that. Since you already got an answer to this question, you better post a new question including the structure of the data you intend to read from the array.

Comment: @David Heffernan all my code is running in both worlds. I compile it with Delphi 2007 and Lazarus(FPC). Therefore i decided to use the delphi and the freepascal tag.

Comment: With generics it is possible to write a class (or record) that accesses only part of the array. In Delphi, due to how dynamic arrays are stored in memory, it is not possible to create a *slice* or *view* or whatever it is called in other languages **as `TByteArray`** without copying though. And if you copy, it does not refer to the original array anymore. So it is possible with a (generic, if necessary) class, but not directly with a `TByteArray` as result. And if this must work in FreePascal too, it gets a little more complicated. It could work if you only target `TByteArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. A dynamic array contains meta data located immediately before the first element of the array. That's not compatible with you wanting a dynamic array whose first element is in the middle of another array.

You will probably need to solve your problem using a pointer to the first element of the sub array.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer i suspectec something like that.

Comment: @David: "a pointer to the first element of the sub array" and an associated length.